# how to I override the value of APP_VERSION substitution string in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In my apex application I want to display custom application version. From the page template I see that it is using substution string APP_VERSION.
I tried changing this in application properties > Difinition > Substitution String. But it is not reflecting the changes.

Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding application level item APP_VERSION. Added this as &APP_VERSION at field application properties > Definition > Name: Version.

In an Application Process, application level item APP_VERSION is assigned a value after reading a property in database table.

Comment: Why don't you just use the application version in application properties > Definition > Name: Version. ?

Comment: I am using the same, just added the feature that will pull the version from DB

Comment: Possibly a future version of apex will support setting/retrieving the application version with an API, then this worksaround will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `APP_VERSION` is a substitution string. It cannot be overridden by a user defined substitution string. It takes the value from application properties > Definition > Name: Version.

This substitution string can be used in file url definition and as a template substitution string. It cannot be used in apps using the `&P_ITEM.` syntax and is not available in pl/sql as a bind variable.